# A ring $R$ is noetherian iff whenever $S_1,S_2,\ldots$ are simple right $R$-modules then $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty}E(S_i)$ is injective.

Tags: ring-theory, modules, noetherian, injective-module

It's well-known that a ring $R$ is noetherian if and only if direct sums of injective $R$-modules are again injective.

How to prove the following characterization:
$R$ is noetherian $\iff$ whenever $S_1,S_2,\ldots$ are simple right $R$-modules then $\bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty}E(S_i)$ is injective as well, where $E(S_i)$ is the injective hull of $S_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the direct sum of any countable collection of injective hulls of simple left $R$-modules is injective.

If $R$ is not left noetherian, there is an ascending chain of left ideals  $I_1 \subsetneq I_2 \subsetneq I_3 \subsetneq \cdots$ which not stops.
Let $I = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$, and
note that for each $x \in I$ we have that $(x+I_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty I/I_n$, giving us a map $\tau \colon I \to \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty I/I_n$.

Now, for each $n \geq 1$ we choose $x_n$ in $I \setminus I_n$, so that we can find a simple left $R$-module $S_n$ and a map $\sigma_n \colon I/I_n \to \text{E}(S_n)$ with $\sigma_n(x_n+I_n) \neq 0$.
Let $\sigma$ be $\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_n \colon \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty I/I_n \to \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \text{E}(S_n)$.

Then, $\sigma \circ \tau \colon I \to \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \text{E}(S_n)$ extends to a map $\rho \colon R \to \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \text{E}(S_n)$.
Observe that, as $\rho(1)$ has almost all of its entries equal to zero, there exists $N \geq 1$ with the property that every element of $\rho(R)$ has a zero in each entry starting from the $N$-th one; a contradiction since the $N$-th entry of $\rho(x_N)$ is non-zero.

Comment: How to guarantee the existence of a simple left $R$-module $S_n$ and a homomorphism $\sigma_n:I/I_n \to E(S_n)$ ?!.

Comment: If $x$ is a non-zero element of a left $R$-module $M$, then there is a simple left $R$-module $S$ and a map $f \colon M \to \text{E}(S)$ with $f(x) \neq 0$. *Proof*: Since $Rx$ is finitely generated, it has a maximal submodule, say, $L$. Then $Rx/L$ is simple and the canonical projection $Rx \twoheadrightarrow Rx/L$ maps $x$ to a non-zero element. Now simply extend the domain of $Rx \twoheadrightarrow Rx/L \hookrightarrow \text{E}(Rx/L)$ to $M$.

Comment: Excuse me dude, you constructed a nonzero homomorphism $Rx \to E(Rx/L)$. But this homomorphism can't be extended to the entire module (unless the module is quasi-injective).

Comment: @HusseinEid It can, $\text{E}(Rx/L)$ *is* injective by definition.

Comment: Baer's Criterion for injectivity states that: *A left module $M$ is injective if and only if any $R$-module homomorphism $f:I\to M$ from a left ideal $I\subseteq R$ can be extended to $R$*. 

My question is: Is $Rx$ a left ideal of $R$ ?!. $M$ in your proof is an arbitrary module. @azif00

Comment: @HusseinEid Definition of injectivity: *A left $R$-module $Q$ is injective if and only if for any submodule $N$ of a left $R$-module $M$, every $R$-module homomorphism $N \to Q$ can be extended to $M$*. Note that the Baer’s criterion says that it suffices to check the extension property for $M=R$, but I didn’t use it on my proof.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I'm really so sorry.